# Laravel Download files from database

Tags: php, laravel, file

This is my question: 
I've a system where the user can see the information about a particular post; for expample in the section "Sales" the user can see all the information about one product; and in every product, the user can donwload the files, like download a PDF; or mp3, in this case, a mp3 file:
Well, the system save all the records about the files that the user downloaded, and after save the records, download the file:
My exactly problem is, the record of the files donwloaded save in database, but, never start the download; I've 2 relations, and are, a audiobook can have multiples download, but, a donwload, just have 1 audiobook:

```
public function downloads() //One download for one audiobook
{
    return $this->hasMany('\bdc\AudiobookDownload');
}

public function audiobooks() //Multiples download for one audiobook
{
    return $this->belongsTo('\bdc\AudioBook');
}
```

This is my code, where the download suposse start:

```
public function downloadAudiobook($id)
{
        if (Auth::user())
        {
            $userCheck = Auth::user()->$id;
            $download = AudiobookDownload::where(['user_id' => $userCheck, 'audiobooks_id' => $id])->first();
            if (empty($download->user_id))
            {
                $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
                $audiobooks_id = $id;
                $download = new AudiobookDownload;
                $download->user_id = $user_id;
                $download->audiobooks_id = $audiobooks_id;
                $download->save();
            }
        $download = public_path().'/uploads/audiobooks/audiobook_location/' . $download->audiobooks_id .'.m‌​p3';
            return response()->download($download);
        }
        else
        {
            return redirect()->route('login')->with('validate', 'Por favor inicia sesión para descargar este audiolibro');
        }
}
```

All the files are inside a folder, inside the public folder of the proyect, and the route of the folder are in DB:

```
$table->string('audiobook_location')->nullable();
```

And I got this error:

> (1/1) FileNotFoundException The file
>   "/home/vagrant/Code/BDC/public/uploads/audiobooks/audiobook_location/1.m‌​p3"
>   does not exist

Where is 1.mp3, have to be the name of the file that the user is trying download

I need download just one file, of one post; if someone can help me, I'll be really grateful!

Comment: `all the files that are saved in Database` - where are they saved, in what model? What are the relationships between your models?  You have an `audiobooks_id`, isn't the filename in the record with that ID?

Comment: there are 2 different variables `$download` and `$downloads`,
also change `public_path().'/uploads/audiobooks/audiobook_location/test.m‌​p3'`, to `public_path().'/uploads/audiobooks/audiobook_location/'. $download->audiobooks_id .'.m‌​p3'`  and pass `$audiobook` not `$downloads` to `download` method

Comment: Well, the file saved in the public path, the route of the public path is in database, and, when an administrator upload a new post, will upload those files: The relations are for show all the records in the profile of the users, that's ok, now, I will change the variables and try, let me see

Comment: @Don'tPanic audiobooks_id references the Id on the table audiobook, and the relations in this case, is hasMany downloads in the Model Audiobook.php and BelongsTo audiobooks in AudiobookDonwload.php: 
public function downloads()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('\bdc\AudiobookDownload');
    }
public function audiobooks()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('\bdc\AudioBook');
    }

I have this, cause, after download I need to show the downloads of every user, and, It's correct all of this
And, the files are inside public folder, where are all the files of the proyects dividided

Comment: But, I got the next error, I change my code to download, and now, I've this: 
$download = public_path().'/uploads/audiobooks/audiobook_location/' . $download->audiobooks_id .'.m‌​p3';
                return response()->download($download);
And the result after click the button; where suppose start to download is this the result:
The file "/home/vagrant/Code/BDC/public/uploads/audiobooks/audiobook_location/1.m‌​p3" does not exist
I need change 1.mp3, for Moby_dick.mp3 or any other file inside the folder

Comment: Edit your question and add your relationships, properly formatted. If there is new information or errors, add them to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't shown your routes, but I am guessing you have one something like:

```
Route::get('/some/path/download/{id}', 'someController@downloadAudiobook');
```

And I think the `$id` passed to your `downloadAudiobook` method must be the id of an audiobook?

First, this line does not make sense, since the `$id` here is not related to the logged in user:

```
$userCheck = Auth::user()->$id;
```

I think you want the user ID of the logged in user:

```
$userCheck = Auth::user()->id;
```

Next - you haven't shown us your Audiobook model, but I am assuming you must have a `filename` column - or is that the `audiobook_location` you mention?  So you can retrieve the audibook record and use the filename in your download response:

```
$audiobook = AudioBook::find($id);
$download = public_path().'/uploads/audiobooks/audiobook_location/' . $audiobook->audiobook_location;
```

Complete code:

```
public function downloadAudiobook($id)
{
        if (Auth::user())
        {
            $userID = Auth::user()->id;
            $download = AudiobookDownload::where(['user_id' => $userID, 'audiobooks_id' => $id])->first();
            if (empty($download->user_id))
            {
                $download = new AudiobookDownload;
                $download->user_id = $user_id;
                $download->audiobooks_id = $id;
                $download->save();
            }

            $audiobook = AudioBook::find($id);
            $download = public_path().'/uploads/audiobooks/audiobook_location/' . $audiobook->audiobook_location;
            return response()->download($download);
        }
        else
        {
            return redirect()->route('login')->with('validate', 'Por favor inicia sesión para descargar este audiolibro');
        }
}
```

Comment: I already try with your answer, and I'm really, really grateful with you, man
You help me now with 2 questions, and you give me the answer of both, I really don't know how can repay you your help, but now, I'm really grateful with you, thanks a lot man!